# ZonedDateTime output different on Android 13

Tags: android, java-time, zoneddatetime

I'm getting two different date outputs on different versions of Android

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("Mon, 31 Jul 2023 18:57:55 +0000", DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

On Android 13 the output is:

```
2023-07-31 14:57:55
```

on Android 9 and 11 the output is:

```
2023-07-31 18:57:55
```

If I log `ZoneId.systemDefault()` all versions return: America/New_York

Android 13 has the correct date. However if I used a `LocalDateTime` instead of `ZonedDateTime` then the wrong date is also outputted on Android 13.

Same result happens if I use

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("Mon, 31 Jul 2023 18:57:55 +0000", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z").withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

Update: I tried changing the time zone to "America/Los_Angeles" and this is the result for a different date:

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("Tue, 01 Aug 2023 10:00:00 -0000", DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

Android 13: 2023-08-01 03:00:00

Android 11: 2023-08-01 10:00:00
```

I should add I am converting all of my `java.util.Date` code to `java.time` and this didn't happen with the old code.